# How do companies handle changing natural language

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings

I am assuming large social medias like Twitter handle hashtags using some sort of embedding, so that similar tweets can be found or suggested. Maybe this is a bad assumption- maybe someone can clarify.
However, the question I have is how they handle new vocabulary being added? For example, whenever a new hashtag becomes trending, it is likely or at least possible that that exact string had not been included in the vocabulary of the embedding before then. Since embedding vocabulary cannot be changed after the fact, is it possible that they simply retrain their model every few hours? That seems to be intractable.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of common options:

- Fine-tuning: Given new data (both new tokens and changes in data distribution), unfreeze existing model weights and do additional model training. Almost all of the models are trained with stochastic gradient descent (SGD) which supports online learning.
- Use sub-word features: Include fragments of language in the model. For example if "ing" is in the model, when new words appear that end in "ing" there is high likelihood they are novel verbs. The most extreme example of sub-word features is including individual characters in the
  model.

Comment: I was under the impression that implementations like word2vec can be trained on new pairs, but cannot expand or change the vocabulary once the weight vector is created?

Comment: New tokens can be added to existing models. Each new token is initialized with a random location/weights. Then model is trained as typical.